# Toggle like button to create and remove input box

Tags: javascript, html

Am creating an HTML page with some buttons to create the input boxes. The buttons should behave like toggle one. ie, on first click input box should appear and if the same button in clicked again that particular input box need to disappear. Button toggle i have managed. But div is not creating
This is my toggle button

```
<button class="btn" id="button_rd" onclick="setColor('button_rd', '#101010')";>one</button>
```

Following is the javascript

```
var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
             property.style.backgroundColor = "#f4543c"//red
             property.style.borderColor = "#f4543c"
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#00a65a"//green
            property.style.borderColor = "#008d4c"
            count = 0;

            var newdiv = '<div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">email</label>'
            +'<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"></div>'
            document.getElementById("create").append(newdiv);
        }
    }
```

And below is the place where I need the input box to display(inside this div)

```
<div class="box-body" id="create">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
document.getElementById("create").append(newdiv);
```

'innerHTML' works for me, like below:

```
document.getElementById("create").innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1">email</label>'
            +'<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"></div>'
```

to remove the div on toggle i used

```
$('div_id').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use Jquery, [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ncpjj938/1/) may be what you're looking for.

it's not so much as 'creating' an element, more actually 'toggling' its visibility

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=bool]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substr($(this).attr("id").length - 1);
    $('[id^=bool' + id + '] .switcher').toggleClass("switched");
    var x = $('[id=input' + id + ']').length;
    if (x > 0) //there is one there
    {
      $('[id=input' + id + ']').remove();
    } else {
      $('body').append('<input type="text" id="input' + id + '" placeholder="input ' + id + '" />');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.bool {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: darkgray;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 6px gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.bool:before {
  content: "On";
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
.bool:after {
  content: "Off";
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
.switcher {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgray;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px black;
}
.switched {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bool" id="bool1">
  <div class="switcher"></div>
</div>
<div class="bool" id="bool2">
  <div class="switcher"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit History**

- *Altered snippet to include 2 toggles, as per comments*
- *refactored jquery method with help from [Tambo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065597/tambo)*
- *altered markup to 'append' and 'remove' instead*

Comment: this is not a pure javascript solution since you're using jquery. the question is not tagged with jquery.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans: hence why I stated *If you're happy to use Jquery*

Comment: This one helps.But in my page there is many number of input boxes. So what am thinking is creating new inputs depending on button click. Am i thinking in the right way ? thanks for your quick answer @jbutler483

Comment: @jbutler483: separate toggle for each button. so that each button will generate input boxes accordingly

Comment: @jason: Jquery has been refactored too

Comment: @jbutler483: appreciate your help. But what i exactly need is to create a div. Because this input box may vary so that in future i dont want to edit in code.

Comment: @jason: sorry for such long comments, but I have edied again to physically add and remove the text boxes

Comment: @jbutler483: thanx butler. Will try Jquery. But i got the 'innerHTML' works for me. Will post it

Answer (score 0):

OnClick write following code to **hide:**

```
document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none';
```

And following code to **show:**

```
document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'block';
```

Like:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 1;

function hidShow()
{
if(count == 1)
{
    document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none';
    count = 0;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'block';
    count = 1;
}
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="button_rd" onClick="hidShow()">one</button>

<div class="box-body" id="create">
    <input type="text" id="txt"/>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciate your help @ketan. But what i exactly need is to create a div. Because this input box may vary so that in future i dont want to edit in code.